# Video doesn't play on loop or repeat (vlcj-java)

Tags: java, windows, loops, media-player, vlcj

I am using vlcj on my java program. I need the video to play repeatedly. I've used setRepeat(true); but it doesn't work for me. Is this any other to loop the video? Or am I doing it wrong? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

```
 public QueueMonitor() {
                    
        initComponents();
         
        //VIDEO
        chargerLibrairie();

        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        panel.add(c);
        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        //Create a media player instance
        EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
        
        mediaPlayer.playMedia("Ospital1.mp4");
        mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);
        mediaPlayer.setPlaySubItems(true);

       
    }


    public static void chargerLibrairie(){
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
        RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        LibXUtil.initialise();
    }
```

Also, how can I put some functions like pause, play, lower volume while the program is running? Like how a normal video player is able to do.

Comment: Your posted code makes the common mistake of not keeping references to your media player objects - in this case "mediaPlayer" goes out of scope and becomes eligible for garbage collection when your QueueMonitor() constructor exits. You need to fix those issues first before it's possible to say why repeat-play isn't working.

Comment: what exactly do i need to do to keep reference to the media player objects?

Comment: since this is not an answer to the posted question, i'll just drop a link https://capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj-4/tutorials/garbage-collection

Answer (score 1):

Here are some minimal examples of how to get repeat play working with vlcj.

For current versions of vlcj, 4.x and later:

```
// vlcj 4.x+
public class RepeatPlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String mrl = "some-cool-video.mp3";

        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Repeat Player");
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mediaPlayerComponent.release();
            }
        });
        f.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
        f.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().controls().setRepeat(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play(mrl);

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

Since it looks like you're using an ancient version of vlcj, this is how it was done previously:

```
// vlcj 3.12.1
public class RepeatPlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String mrl = "some-cool-video.mp3";

        final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Repeat Player");
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mediaPlayerComponent.release();
            }
        });
        f.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
        f.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().setRepeat(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mrl);

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

---

The code in the original question was therefore broadly correct at least with regards to the repeat-play functionality. The most likely problem with the original code is that the media player was garbage collected due to a failure to hold the object references.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Video extends javax.swing.JPanel
{

  private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent video;
  private EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 
 public Video()
  {
    initComponents();
    initVideo();
  }

  private void initVideo()
  {
    video = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent()
    {
      @Override
      public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
      {
        super.finished(mediaPlayer);
        System.out.println("FINISHED");
        new Thread(() -> {
          System.gc();
          mediaPlayer.controls().setTime(0);
          mediaPlayer.controls().play();
        }).start();
      }
    };
    mediaPlayer = video.mediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.input().enableKeyInputHandling(false);
    mediaPlayer.input().enableMouseInputHandling(false);
    add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  }
  public void start(String path)
  {
    mediaPlayer.media().prepare(path);
    mediaPlayer.controls().play();
  }
  public void stop()
  {
    mediaPlayer.controls().stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    video.release();
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void initComponents()
  {
    setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).